# why is this page triggering compatibility mode in ie?

Tags: internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

The markup is valid, I've been trying for a couple of hours by now, but I still fall in compatibility mode, on both IE8 and IE9..any hint would be great..

[here's the link to the page](http://www.dmdcode.it/lavori/fabriziosmania/progetti.php)

P.S. I've already tried adding

```
<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=8” />
```

etc etc

Comment: After some other testing, I discovered that there was a CSS property that was triggering the compatibility view. exactly max-width. @Vàclav: thanks for the support man :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some other testing, I discovered that there was a CSS property that was triggering the compatibility view. exactly max-width.

Answer (score 0):

My IE9 is in *IE9 Standards* mode. Check you have turned *Compatibility View* off. When you click on it manually, IE remembers that even after restart.

You have to declare `content="IE=9"` in order to force *IE9 Standards* mode.